# Which string can't be accessed?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

We start from the string $ABCDEF$ and we can edit it with the following rules:

> 1.$ABCDEF \Rightarrow ADBECF$
>
> 2.$ABCDEF \Rightarrow DAEBFC$

Which string can't be accessed?

> 1. DBAFEC
> 2. FCBEDA
> 3. CABEFD
> 4. EFDCAB
> 5. FEDCBA

In these kind of problems we usually look for a common thing in every change of the the string, which I can't do here.

According to the book, the answer is

> string $5$.

**Math SE copy**: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444884/which-string-cant-accessed

Comment: For content that is not your own, please provide attribution. Using someone else's content without (at minimum) disclosing where it came from is plagiarism, and such posts are deleted.

Comment: Not to mention cross posting is generally discouraged without good reason.